# javascript value does not add up

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I try to make a count up function whenever there is pressed on a button (button is not in  this code).
the result of the count up should be in the read only text field.

```
var html='';
    var huidig = 0;
    $('body').off('click', '[data-type=product]').on('click', '[data-type=product]', function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
        var name =  $(this).attr('data-name');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        if($('input[value='+id+']').length > 0) 
        {
            var parent = $('input[value='+id+']').parent();
            console.log("parent: " + parent);

            var currentValue = parseFloat(parent.find('input[name^=product_amount]').val());
            console.log("currentValue: " + currentValue);
            currentValue++;
            console.log("currentValue: " + currentValue);

            parent.find('input[name^=product_amount]').val(parseFloat(currentValue));
            console.log(parent.find('input[name^=product_amount]').val(parseFloat(currentValue)));
        }
        else 
        {
            html+='<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span1"><input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="'+id+'"/><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="product_amount[]" value="0" /></div>  <div class="span7">'+name+'</div>  <div class="span3 offset1">&euro;'+price+'</div>  </div>';
        }

        $('.bill').html(html);
        amount = amount + parseFloat(price);
        $('.total_bill').html(amount.toFixed(2));
    });
```

Comment: `.` is a class selector. This will return an array of results. Not sure if this will affect your code

Comment: 'Not add up', how exactly? Explain. Failures to understand floating-point arithmetic or to round it correctly are common.. your code appears to do something (whether correct or not, I'm not yet sure) to round or truncate `amount` but OTOH I can't see where `amount` is declared.

Comment: It's not clear enough from your question and code what the issue is here. What is happening? Are you getting any errors? As Thomas has suggested from our point of view you could be confused about floating-point arithmetic as jasonscript has mentioned if `.total_bill` is used as a class on multiple elements then `.html()` won't work as there will be an array of results.

Comment: Can you post a JS-fiddle? Also, it might be that you have `[]` in your input names, but in the jQuery selector you don't include these.

Comment: declaration of amount is been done on top of my JavaScript file also not in this code.
in the bottom part of the code are no errors. this one counts up fine.
the problem is between the if and else part

Comment: a JS-fiddle: jsfiddle.net/xVAPg, If you press on a button there it should add the name below, if you press the same button there should be a 2 in the readonly textfeeld. it is the currentValue that doesn't want to add up. the others work

Comment: If I understand properly you want the following: for each button pressed to show number in the field. Currently it is always 0. For example: 3 fanta, 5 zero... and total at the end. It seems that total is calculated correctly, but you get only 0 instead of number of items

Comment: You retrieve `currentValue`, update it but do not save it. So it is always 0 when fatch it  the next time.

Comment: how do i save it than i tried different ways non worked